# How to pass the values entered by the user in template to the function as argument in django?

Tags: django, forms, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I want to take the input value given by the user i.e ratings in this case and want to call the specified function but that function doesnot return anything .So i want to stay in the same page after I click submit .[Image to display the page where input is taken.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTksY.jpg)

This is code to the details page .

```
<h4>Hai this is the details page for the movies {{ plot }}</h4>
<form action="#" method="post">
     {% csrf_token %}
  Ratings: <input type="number" name="quantity" step="0.5" min="1" max="5"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Click">
</form>
```

This is the function which i need to call by passing the value given by user and this function does not return anything instead it stores the value to the csv file.

```
def rate_movie(user_id , movie_id , rating_value):
    pc = ratings.movie_id[ratings.user_id == user_id]  # gets all the movies rated by this user
    ad = pc.tolist() #converts to list
    s = 0
    # This loop finds the exact location in the table to store the rating.
    for p in ad:
        if movie_id < p:
            s =  ad.index(p)
            break
    #Splits the table at this point.
    seperate = list(pc[pc == s].index)[0]
    #The row which will be added to the table.
    bla = [user_id,movie_id,rating_value,665345]
    #Splitting the table
    pq = ratings[:seperate+1]
    rs = ratings[seperate+1:len(ratings)]
    pq.loc[len(pq)] = bla
    pq.index = pq.index + 1
    pq = pq.append(rs , ignore_index=True)
    pq.to_csv("/home/iffu/Documents/ratingsss.csv",index = False)
```

Comment: Well, looks like you're a bit confused about the `stuff` should work. First of all I see you are using the verb GET instead of the POST to pass the value and this is quite _unsafe_. Then you should read the ZEN of python (what does mean the variables pq, bla, s, pc?) Please, be explicit! Instead of saving into csv why you don't put a return statement? Looks like you copied the code somewhere without having an idea of what you are doing... but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Now i have changed the get to post ..